# why wkwebview hides under navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, wkwebview

I have a view controller which only has webview and I have constraints to top, leading,trailing as zero.

When I am presenting the viewcontroller with full screen , Webview goes underneath the navigation bar.( above iOS 13 but it's showing fine when its iOS 12 )

```
let rootViewController = NavigationController(rootViewController: myViewController)
        rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        initiatingViewController.present(rootViewController, animated: true)
```

I tried setting the top constraint as 44 but still not working.

Any helpful pointers please

Comment: Attach a picture of what it looks like on the app, and preferably more code.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue.

- Choose to ViewController in storyboard
- Choose **Attributes inspector**
- Look for **Extend edges** section over there
- Disable Under **top bars**

This worked for me.I hope this might help u